# How to shorten the distance between label and figure after using multiplot

Tags: plot, size, gnuplot, colorbox

I have a layout of 1,3 plots using multiplot. However, the distance between label and tics and figures becomes larger than without using multiplot.

The script is :

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced   # format of figure file
set output 'u_cmp.eps'   # filename of output
set size 1.0,0.45   # size of canvas

set multiplot layout 1,3

set origin 0.0, 0.0

unset key  # do not show text following keyword "plot"

set x2label "x(km)" font ",10"  # x top
set ylabel "z(km)" font ",10"

set x2tics font ",10"
set ytics font ",10"

set size ratio 1.5

set x2tics out
set ytics out

set xrange [0:71]
set yrange [0:1000] reverse  # y axis pointing downward
unset xtics
set ytics nomirror

set palette file "-"
0 0 1
1 1 1
1 0 0
e

set x2tics ( "0.0" 0.0, "0.5" 20, "1.0" 40, "1.5" 60)

set ytics ( "0.0" 0.0, "0.3" 300, "0.6" 600, "0.9" 900)
unset colorbox
set tics scale 0.6

set size 0.3, 0.45   # size of canvas
set origin 0.0, 0.0

set rmargin at screen 0.3
plot "./ustat_mute" binary array=(414,1000) format="%float" with image 

set size 0.3, 0.45   # size of canvas
set origin 0.3, 0.0

set rmargin at screen  0.6
plot "../data_c12/ustat_mute" binary array=(414,1000) format="%float" with image

set colorbox 
set colorbox size 0.1,0.45
set size 0.3,0.45
set origin 0.6,0.0

set rmargin at screen 0.9
plot "../data_c11/ustat_mute_cmp" binary array=(414,1000) format="%float" with image
```

Comment: Its quite hard to tell what you mean, because the script is quite long, we don't know the output, and we don't have the data file to reproduce your problem. Can you simplify your script with e.g. three `plot x` graphs or similar?

Comment: In accordance to what Christoph said, can you provide a copy/paste example that illustrates your problem, please?